# Russell's paradox explanation

Tags: paradoxes

The Russell's paradox deals with the set of all sets that do not contain themselves.
So I want a example of a set that do not contain themselves.
I got a examples of set of turtles.It will contain turtles, but I want to understand how should I understand the set of all turtles is not member of the set.

Comment: Is set of all turtles turtle?

Comment: The set of all turtles is not a turtle. Therefore, the set of all turtles is a set which does not contain itself.

Comment: Technically, the verb you should use is _own_ ($\owns$), not _contain_ ($\supseteq$).

Comment: The simplest example is the empty set

Comment: If you really want to understand Russell's paradox in the context of understanding ZF set theory you should be aware that the sets we consider here have no "ur-elements"; in mathematics we have no idea what a turtle is or anything else. The sets in ZF have elements which are *other sets*, and everything is just built up from the empty set which has no elements at all (and so which trivially does not contain itself).

Answer (score 0):

Think of a set as a box. But it's a special kind of box, because it's defined entirely by what's inside it. I can put a label on the box to tell me what it is, but if I have two boxes that have exactly the same things inside them then they're actually two copies of the same box.

So you show me your box, and it's labelled "All Turtles". I look inside it, and indeed everything in the box is a turtle, and in fact every possible turtle is inside the box. And I can ask you - does the box contain itself? Well, the only thing in the box is turtles, so if the box isn't a turtle then it can't contain itself.

Then I give you another box, and it's labelled "All Boxes". Does the box contain itself? It should - every box that can possibly exist is inside this box, which includes itself. So I can open this box, find a box labelled "All Boxes" in it, and it would be indistinguishable from the original one. There would *also* be a box in there labelled "All Turtles", and it would contain all the turtles in it. But we would *not* say that the "All Boxes" box contained turtles, because we never go more than one step down to determine what's inside a box.

Russell's paradox comes about when we use more complicated labels for the boxes. Maybe I have a box labelled "All Boxes that don't contain turtles". And another one labelled "All Boxes that contain exactly one box", and one that's "All Boxes that don't contain any boxes with turtles in them". And then finally "All Boxes that don't contain themselves", and it all breaks down and we have to set rules about what kinds of contents boxes are actually allowed to have.